# FIlter entries by category without refreshing the page

Tags: categories, conditionals, ajax, filter, advanced-conditionals

I have a page that displays all entries in a "stories" channel. Each story is categorised and I need there to be an option to filter by these categories. Here is the code I currently have:

```
<div class="filter-stories">
    Filter stories by:
    {exp:channel:categories channel="stories" style="linear" show_empty="no"}
        <a href="#">{category_name}</a>
    {/exp:channel:categories}
</div>

{exp:channel:entries channel="stories" dynamic="off"}
    <aricle class="story{switch='|| end'}" style="border:1px solid #000;width: 32%; float: left;">
        <img src="{story-hero}" style="width:100%;">
        <h1>{categories}{category_name}{/categories}</h1>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        {story-text-1}
        <a href="{page_url}">read more</a>
    </aricle>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Currently the list shows all the stories - which is how I want it to be by default, but how would I go about making the filter work. Ideally I want to click one of the category name links and it will only show the stories in that category without refreshing the page (using AJAX I assume?).

I've never used AJAX in ExpressionEngine, can I add to the channel entries tag with it or is there a different way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great 2-part walkthrough of a setup like this on the [Meta Q](http://themetaq.com/mobile/articles/ajax-ee-sort-and-order-data-with-expressionengine-and-ajax-part-one) site that would be worth a read.

Comment: You're very welcome. I love it when there's a step-by-step tutorial on how to do something. Makes life so much easier!